# Как передать значение переменной из одной функции в другую?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

У меня есть функция, вызывающая форму, где я ввожу данные `user`. Мне необходимо из этой функции передать `user` в другую.
Реализация следующая `views.py`:

функция для ввода пользовательских данных:

```py
def index(request):
    model = Users.objects.all()
    user = Users()
    form = AuthUserForm(request.POST if request.POST else None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #в этом if я нахожу нужного мне user
        return render(request, 'main/user.html', {'user': user})
    
    return render(request, 'main/login.html', {'form': form, 'user': user})
```

и вторая функция, где мне нужно использовать этот `user`

```py
def change_password(request):
    user = Users()
    form = Change_Password(request.POST if request.POST else None)
    return render(request, 'main/change_password.html', {'form': form, 'user': user})
```

я только разбираюсь в Django. рассмотрю любые варианты решения.

Comment: Можете просто сделать переменную ```user``` глобальной (```global user```)

Answer (score 0):

При смене пароля, может подразумеваться две вещи

1. Смена пароля при неавторизированном пользователе, тогда простейшая логика отправить письмо на почту с ссылкой на смену (есть готовая реализация в django [туториал на английском](https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-password-reset-tutorial))
2. Смена пароля, когда авторизация пройдена. Первое, не используйте глобальной переменной в данной рутине. Второе, `request` уже будет содержать поле `user` и к нему можно обратиться так

   ```py
   def change_password(request):
       if request.method == "POST":
          user = request.user # текущий пользователь страницы
   ```

   Переменная `user` в этом случае будет содержать одну из двух сущностей:

   - если пользователь не залогинен, тогда `анонминый пользователь` - [AnonymousUser](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser)
   - если пользователь залогинен, тогда `пользователь` - [User](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User)

   Чтобы проверить залогинен ли пользователь, уже существует функция для этого

   ```py
   request.user.is_authenticated # возвращает True/False
   ```

Передавать пользователя между функциями в вашем случае не имеет смысла, работайте с текущим пользователем страницы `request.user`.